# Can We Generate Resource.resx and its Designer.cs Files in .NET Core Using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core, localization, globalization, resource-files

Is it Possible to Create a Resource.resx File and Its Corresponding Designer.cs File in .NET Core Using Visual Studio Code?

I attempted to create a Resource.resx file by installing the ResX Viewer and Editor, which was successful. However, the corresponding Designer.cs file did not generate as expected.